# Ansible "provided hosts list is empty" error

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I created an inventory file has .yml extension like below:

```
---
  all:
    server1
    hosts:
      server2
    children:
      hana:
        prod:
          client1:
            hosts:
              server3
          client2:
            hosts:
              server4
        test:
          client1:
            hosts:
              server5
          client1:
            hosts:
              server6
...
```

Then I ran ping ad-hoc for all hosts with below command:

```
ansible -m ping -i /etc/ansible/inventories/linuxall.yml all
```

And I saw these warnings and ping didn't work:

```
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/inventories/linuxall.yml as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

Why ansible cannot parse my inventory? Should I do anything for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and solution:

There is a section named [inventory] in the ansible.cfg file. Remove # character at the start of line "enable inventory plugins...". Then .yml and .yaml inventory files will been activated.

Also, ":" character is necessary after every line else hostnames too.

Answer (score 1):

In the example on the following link every line, including the server names, ends with a colon character:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Comment: thanks. I saw this tutorial. I found the the reason of the problem. I'll add an solution asap. It's not about the file, it's about config file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was:
I needed to specify the location of playbook.yml with the `-K` switch

```
ansible-playbook -K /root/myplatform/playbook.yml
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-k says that `-K` is the "ask for privilege escalation password" switch, not the switch to specify the location of playbook.yml